# Intermittent, inconsistent issue deleting BigObjects

Tags: apex, platform-bug, big-object

we have an intermittent issue when deleting big objects. We have a scheduled job that runs every 30 minutes, and if some conditions are met, it runs the following:

```
try {
    if (!Test.isRunningTest()) System.debug(Database.deleteImmediate(toDel));                    
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.debug('Deletion Failed' + e);
}
```

Where `toDel` is a list of BigObjects.

We intermittently get an email with the following error:

> Apex script unhandled exception by user/organization: /
>
> Scheduled job 'CategoryLoader 25' threw unhandled exception.
>
> caused by: System.UnexpectedException: Programmer error: cannot rollback to savepoint on another transaction
>
> Class.NVMC.CategoryLoader.upload: line 128, column 1
>   Class.NVMC.CategoryLoader.execute: line 6, column 1

Line 128 is exactly the line where we do the `deleteImmediate`.

Note how this is inside a try-catch handler; however, since it's an `UnexpectedException`, it seems uncatchable (see https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008yYoIAI).

The documentation for `deleteImmediate` says:

> If the Apex transaction contains pending changes, the synchronous operations can't be completed and throw exceptions.

(here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm).

What puzzles me is that there are no transactions in the code, and there is no mixed DML (big object/normal sObject). One of our architects thinks that it's an issue in Salesforce when connecting to the BigObject database.  I have raised a Salesforce case and waiting for response. Additionally, I have created a newer package with more streamlined code to see if it makes the issue go away.

My specific questions are:

- Has anybody experienced anything similar?
- How can I explore what's failing further?
- How can I verify the theory that it's a potential bug in Salesforce
- If it is, how do I raise it with SF (other than the case I've already raised?)

Comment: I have never seen something like this before. But as a workaround, have you tried to do the delete in an async method, like a Queueable class?

Comment: I have not. Might give that a try...